# Pybot complains about undefined substitutions (in .rst file)

Tags: python, robotframework, restructuredtext

I have some text in this format in my input *.rst file for robot framework.

```
Education|Education;Business;|G36|match=2; wf=4CXDxrs5|Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I) Appl(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.0.01.12 Safari/3.36|||||9||||
```

When I run pybot , it complains

```
: (ERROR/3) Undefined substitution referenced:    Education|Education;Business;|G36|match=2; wf=4CXDxrs5|Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I) Appl(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.0.01.12 Safari/3.36|||||9||||
```

I understand it thinks i am trying to do text substitution in the rst file, but I need that exact test to be unchanged.

Can I supress this warning in pybot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to suppress that warning in pybot.